# mySQL complicated Joins and evenually pivot

Tags: mysql, join, pivot

I'm working on a shift-scheduling solution and need your help.
The database-layout looks like this: [database-layout](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/9809310/Bildschirmfoto%202013-09-12%20um%2013.28.24.png)

My query to get all schedules for one month looks like this:

```
SELECT
    ca.date,
    ss.num,
    ma.name
FROM dp_dienstplan  AS dp
JOIN ma_mitarbeiter AS ma ON ma.id=dp.dp_mitarbeiter_id
JOIN ss_schienen    AS ss ON ss.id=dp.dp_schienen_id
JOIN sc_schicht     AS sc ON sc.id=ss.ss_schicht_id
RIGHT JOIN calendar AS ca ON ca.date=dp.dp_datum
WHERE
  month(ca.date)=9 AND year(ca.date)=2013
```

The calendar table is a helper-table with dates for the next years to get even days in the result where no schedule is pending.

The Result of the query looks like this:

```
date       |num        |name
----------------------------
2013-09-01  NULL        NULL
2013-09-02  2           foo
2013-09-02  3           bar
2013-09-03  2           uncle
2013-09-03  1           mac
2013-09-03  7           super
2013-09-04  NULL        NULL
2013-09-04  2           master
.
.
.
2013-09-30  NULL        NULL
```

The result what I am dreaming of looks like this:

```
date       |1num |1name |2num |2name |3num |3name. . .|7name|7num 
-----------------------------------------------------------------
2013-09-01  NULL  NULL   NULL  NULL   NULL  NULL . . . NULL  NULL
2013-09-02  NULL  NULL   2     foo    3     bar  . . . NULL  NULL
2013-09-03  1     mac    2     uncle  NULL  NULL . . . 7     super
2013-09-04  NULL  NULL   2     master NULL  NULL . . . NULL  NULL
.           .     .      .     .      .     .          .     . 
.           .     .      .     .      .     .          .     . 
.           .     .      .     .      .     .          .     . 
2013-09-30  NULL  NULL   NULL  NULL   NULL  NULL . . . NULL  NULL
```

There should be one row per single day, with the names and in order of the 'num' value.
I hope you understand what I am talking about, sorry for my english.

I have another helper-table which contains the values from 1 to 200, which I tried to right-join, but I did not succeed.

Thanks in advance, sorry if this is an duplicated question, I did not find any results per google or here on the forums, perhaps because i didn't know for what to search.

Cheers, Ralf.

Comment: Do all numbers `num` are known upfront?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First of all** don't apply functions to a column that you use to filter your data in `WHERE` clause. It prevents MySQL from using any indices you might have on that column effectively causing a fullscan on a table. That being said instead of

```
WHERE month(ca.date)=9 AND year(ca.date)=2013
```

you better do something like

```
WHERE ca.date BETWEEN '2013-09-01' AND LAST_DAY('2013-09-01')
```

And make sure that you have indices on `calendar.date` and `dp_dienstplan.dp_datum`.

---

**Now** if all values of `ss.num` are known upfront you can get your pivot by using conditional aggregation in a static query

```
SELECT ca.date,
       MAX(CASE WHEN ss.num = 1 THEN ss.num  END) `1num`,
       MAX(CASE WHEN ss.num = 1 THEN ss.name END) `1name`,
       MAX(CASE WHEN ss.num = 2 THEN ss.num  END) `2num`,
       MAX(CASE WHEN ss.num = 2 THEN ss.name END) `2name`,
       MAX(CASE WHEN ss.num = 3 THEN ss.num  END) `3num`,
       MAX(CASE WHEN ss.num = 3 THEN ss.name END) `3name`,
       MAX(CASE WHEN ss.num = 4 THEN ss.num  END) `4num`,
       MAX(CASE WHEN ss.num = 4 THEN ss.name END) `4name`,
       MAX(CASE WHEN ss.num = 5 THEN ss.num  END) `5num`,
       MAX(CASE WHEN ss.num = 5 THEN ss.name END) `5name`,
       MAX(CASE WHEN ss.num = 6 THEN ss.num  END) `6num`,
       MAX(CASE WHEN ss.num = 6 THEN ss.name END) `6name`,
       MAX(CASE WHEN ss.num = 7 THEN ss.num  END) `7num`,
       MAX(CASE WHEN ss.num = 7 THEN ss.name END) `7name`
  FROM dp_dienstplan  AS dp
   JOIN ma_mitarbeiter AS ma ON ma.id=dp.dp_mitarbeiter_id
   JOIN ss_schienen    AS ss ON ss.id=dp.dp_schienen_id
   JOIN sc_schicht     AS sc ON sc.id=ss.ss_schicht_id
   RIGHT JOIN calendar AS ca ON ca.date=dp.dp_datum
WHERE ca.date BETWEEN '2013-09-01' AND LAST_DAY('2013-09-01')
GROUP BY ca.date
```

Output:

```
|       DATE |   1NUM |  1NAME |   2NUM |  2NAME |   3NUM |  3NAME |   4NUM |  4NAME |   5NUM |  5NAME |   6NUM |  6NAME |   7NUM |  7NAME |
|------------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|
| 2013-09-01 | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) |
| 2013-09-02 | (null) | (null) |      2 |    foo |      3 |    bar | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) |
| 2013-09-03 |      1 |    mac |      2 |  uncle | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) |      7 |  super |
| 2013-09-04 | (null) | (null) |      2 | master | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) |
| 2013-09-30 | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cad2c/1)** demo *In this demo all your joined tables are emulated by one table that contain sample data that you showed as a result of your query*

Comment: Hello Peter! Thanks a lot for your answer and advise! The names of the columns are not that important. I fetch them to an array which is then JSON'ed to 'handsontable', which handles my editing. Problem is, the values of 'num' are dynamic, they will range between approx. 7 an 70. So the number differs from request to request. As of now, I try creating the sql-statement on-the-fly per php-loop. If you have a different advise you're really welcome :-) Thanks!